# Docker: uwsgi service not recognised

Tags: python, docker, uwsgi

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04.2
RUN rm /bin/sh && ln -s /bin/bash /bin/sh
RUN apt-get -y update && apt-get upgrade -y
RUN apt-get install python build-essential python-dev python-pip python-setuptools -y
RUN apt-get install libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev python-dev -y
RUN apt-get install libpq-dev postgresql-common postgresql-client -y
RUN apt-get install openssl openssl-blacklist openssl-blacklist-extra -y
RUN apt-get install nginx -y
RUN pip install "pip>=7.0"
RUN pip install virtualenv uwsgi

ADD canonicaliser_api /home/ubuntu/canonicaliser_api
ADD config_local.py /home/ubuntu/canonicaliser_api/config/config_local.py
RUN virtualenv /home/ubuntu/canonicaliser_api/venv
RUN source /home/ubuntu/canonicaliser_api/venv/bin/activate && pip install -r /home/ubuntu/canonicaliser_api/requirements.txt
RUN export CFLAGS=-I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/numpy/core/include/
RUN source /home/ubuntu/canonicaliser_api/venv/bin/activate && cd /home/ubuntu/canonicaliser_api/canonicaliser/cython_extensions/ && python setup.py build_ext --inplace
RUN cp /home/ubuntu/canonicaliser_api/canonicaliser/cython_extensions/canonicaliser/cython_extensions/*.so /home/ubuntu/canonicaliser_api/canonicaliser/cython_extensions
RUN rm -rf /home/ubuntu/canonicaliser_api/canonicaliser/cython_extensions/canonicaliser
RUN rm -r /home/ubuntu/canonicaliser_api/canonicaliser/cython_extensions/build

RUN mkdir /var/run/flask-uwsgi
RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /var/run/flask-uwsgi
RUN mkdir /var/log/flask-uwsgi
RUN touch /var/log/flask-uwsgi/dqs_canon.log
RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /var/log/flask-uwsgi
RUN mkdir /etc/flask-uwsgi

ADD configs/new-canon/flask-uwsgi/flask-uwsgi.conf /etc/init/
ADD configs/new-canon/flask-uwsgi/flask-uwsgi.ini /etc/flask-uwsgi/

EXPOSE 8888
CMD service flask-uwsgi restart

# RUN echo "daemon off;" >> /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
# CMD service nginx start
```

When I try to run this docker I get the error message:

```
flask-uwsgi: unrecognized service
```

So I ended up uncommenting the last two lines, so that nginx gets started and keeps the docker process alive. I then ssh'ed into it to debug.

```
docker exec -it 20b2ff3a4cac bash
```

Now when I try to run the service, it is the same problem and I can't find any missing step.  Maybe services are not allowed to be started like this in docker?

```
root@30b2ff3a4cac:/# service flask-uwsgi start
flask-uwsgi: unrecognized service
```

**/etc/flask-uwsgi/flask-uwsgi.ini**:

```
[uwsgi]
socket = /var/run/flask-uwsgi/flask-uwsgi.sock
home = /home/ubuntu/canonicaliser_api/venv
wsgi-file = flask_uwsgi.py 
callable = app 
master = true
; www-data uid/gid
uid = 33
gid = 33
http-socket = :8888
die-on-term = true
processes = 4
threads = 2
logger = file:/var/log/flask-uwsgi/flask-uwsgi.log
```

**/etc/init/flask-uwsgi.conf:**

```
start on [2345]
stop on [06]

script
    cd /home/ubuntu/canonicaliser_api
    exec uwsgi --ini /etc/flask-uwsgi/flask-uwsgi.ini
end script
```

While ssh'ed into the process, I could run the uwsgi like this directly and it works:

```
exec uwsgi --ini /etc/flask-uwsgi/flask-uwsgi.ini
```

So services are not supported in docker and I have to run this directly in docker image like this:

```
RUN exec uwsgi --ini /etc/flask-uwsgi/flask-uwsgi.ini
```

Or I'm missing something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, don't use services.

You can't do this though:

```
RUN exec uwsgi --ini /etc/flask-uwsgi/flask-uwsgi.ini
```

That line will complete, and be committed to an image. But the process will no longer be running in subsequent instructions or when the container is started.

Instead, you can do it in an ENTRYPOINT or CMD command, as they are executed when the container starts. This should work:

```
CMD uwsgi --ini /etc/flask-uwsgi/flask-uwsgi.ini
```

Some other points:

- you might find things easier if you use one of the [official python images](https://registry.hub.docker.com/_/python/).
- I would just get rid of virtualenv; I don't see the benefit of virtualenv in an isolated container.
- Running `RUN rm -rf ...` doesn't save any space; those files were already committed to a previous layer. You need to delete files in the same instruction they are added to avoid using space in the image.
- It might make sense to do `USER www-data` rather than chowning files.

Comment: Thank you so much for all these tips, I'll make use of them.  I'm new to Docker and still getting my head around it.  I'm now experimenting with `supervised` instead of using a direct CMD.  Since I'll have uwsgi + nginx.

Comment: Yeah, I nearly mentioned supervisord. But you might actually want to try putting nginx in a separate container.

Comment: Excellent. May you elaborate why I should put it in a different container?  Because I need to deploy one image on EC2 where I need all services for the software to work.  Not sure if I follow what you mean by a separate container.

Comment: Why only one image? It's idiomatic to have one process per container. You can do this, have nginx serve static routes and forward other traffic to uwsgi container. Depending on your use case this may or may not be easier.

Comment: I'm planning to put everything into one image and put it on Elastic Beanstalker to scale up when load increases.  I'm preparing a new question just for `supervisord`. In the meanwhile you mentioned use `USER www-data`. Thats a good tip if it gets rid of chowining files.  May you elaborate how to do that?  Do I just add that line in the Dockerfile after installing ubuntu?

Comment: Yes, but it will need to be after any line that needs root privileges, so it will need to be after the apt-gets at least.